# General usage term for "Project"

Tags: word-usage

I am currently designing a project management tool and I want to know if there is a more generic term for *projects*.

For example, event companies undertake *events*, software companies undertake projects etc.

Comment: On Google type "synonym project".

Answer (score 2):

'Event' and 'Project' are *not* synonymous.

A project is a series of connected tasks that, when executed, deliver some required outcome. That outcome could be absolutely anything at all and an "Event" (or anything else for that matter) *could* be delivered by a project, but there is no requirement that it *must* be.

A general term for project could be ['endeavor'](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/endeavour?q=endeavor) (or 'Endeavour' in British English), however whilst all projects are endeavors, not all endeavors are projects!

> **noun**
>
> 1 An attempt to achieve a goal:
>
> [with infinitive]: ‘an endeavour to reduce serious injury’
>
> *www.oxforddictionaries.com*

Answer (score 2):

**[Task](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/task)** is an alternative.

> noun
>
> A piece of work to be done or undertaken.

I do however think 'project' is pretty generic as is.

Answer (score 2):

> > **An assignment**
>
> an undertaking that you have been assigned to do

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/project))

Answer (score 2):

Scheme

//scheme
skiːm/
noun

A large-scale systematic plan or arrangement for attaining some particular object or putting a particular idea into effect.

synonyms:   plan, project, plan of action, programme, strategy, stratagem, game plan;

[Ref](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scheme)

Comment: 'Scheme' is a synonym of Project, but I think the OP is looking for hypernym for all things *like* projects and schemes etc.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, most generic term is: ***"jobs"***.

Comment: thank you so much. will wait for any more suggestions :D